# Adding a new col to dataframe

Tags: r, col

I'am new to R.
Hope You guys will help me out.
I have imported a xlsx into R which is having already 3 col i have add extra col that it should reflect has 4th and 5th col

sample data

```
appid     emi  aid  
12345     12    1
6789      15    2
101212    18    3
```

What i required is

```
appid     emi  aid  4thcol   5th col
12345     12    1    NA          NA
6789      15    2    NA          NA   
101212    18    3    NA          NA
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data to make your question more clear.

Comment: `df[4:5] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question here's a snippet:

```
> df <- data.frame(appid = rnorm(5,3,4), emi = rnorm(5,3,4), aid = rnorm(5,2,2))

> df[4:5] <- NA
```

Output:

```
    > df
       appid         emi       aid V4 V5
1  2.6589136  3.07117782 -1.806979 NA NA
2  4.0774645 -0.52254103  0.874758 NA NA
3  8.0565096 -0.61076733 -1.815436 NA NA
4  1.7483850  0.02000453  3.761556 NA NA
5 -0.3020456  3.64966057  4.607310 NA NA
```

Bonus, to rename the columns use `colnames'.

```
> colnames(df) <- c('w','X','y','Z', 'foo')
```